# enable built-in adminstrator account on SBS2011

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, windows-sbs-2011

In an attempt to uninstall Exchange 2010 I removed some mailboxes (before I would then remove the DB's), but in doing so, it looks like I've removed the AD administration account - named sbsadmin.
It surprises me that removing a mailbox would delete the AD user account, but nonetheless, I have no means of logging onto the server after a restart.
The built-in Administrator account is disabled and there are no other local or AD user accounts at all.

I've tried using the Offline NT Password Editor and even though it went through the motions and "unlocked" and "enabled" the Administrator account and "blanked" the password, I still cannot log in with it.

What options do I have to log in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a way back in...
Using the Directory Services Restore Mode (DSRM) by pressing F8 on startup, then logging in with .\Administrator (no password in my case).
Once logged in, I used regedit to modify the DSRM admin logon behavior key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DSRMAdminLogonBehavior` 
(see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caa05f49-210f-4f4c-b33f-c8ad50a68710) - setting it to "2".
Whilst in DSRM I also added 2 new local admin accounts and made sure they were members of the correct local groups.

Once I was finished in DSRM, I restarted the server in normal mode and logged in with the DSRM account (.\Administrator), opened ADUC and created a brand new domain administration account in AD.

From there I could log in with the new domain admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Always disable, never delete in Exchange.

There is no method of restoring the sbsadmin account in SBS 2011 if you have no backup domain admin account you will be unable to login with any administrative privileges to fix anything.

You'll only guaranteed recovery option at this point is to restore from backup.

Exchange will delete the user account when it is deleted as it is making changes to the AD object directly.

Comment: so no local admin account or anything?
I can get into "recovery mode" run command prompt and create user accounts with "net user /add admin2 Password" then "net localgroup administrators admin2 /add" and that appears to work, but upon restarting, I can't log in with anything I've changed...
I don't really have a backup of this server as it was converted from physical to VM about 6 months ago and rarely ever gets used except for checking historical data.  The changes I was making were to reduce the server load so I can reduce its VM resources...